# Trying to install @angular/material get this error Data path "" should NOT have additional properties(styles)

Tags: angular, npm, jhipster

As the title says i cannot install material in my project, i have searched in google for many hour but it is not been possible to find an answer, i have found many similar problems but none like mine.
After execute this command **ng add @angular/material** a message is thrown.

> An unhandled exception occurred: Workspace config file cannot be
> loaded:
> /Users/myuser/Documents/desarrollos/CODIGO/gatewey/angular.json
> Schema validation failed with the following errors:   Data path ""
> should NOT have additional properties(styles). See
> "/private/var/folders/qz/hsf9v7rx6yz2q1gsz56k3czh0000gn/T/ng-GYq7Rz/angular-errors.log"
> for further details.

and inside the angular-errors.log it says

> [error] Error: Workspace config file cannot be loaded:
> /Users/myuser/Documents/desarrollos/CODIGO/gateway/angular.json Schema
> validation failed with the following errors:   Data path "" should NOT
> have additional properties(styles).
> at Object.getWorkspace (/Users/myuser/Documents/desarrollos/CODIGO/gateway/node_modules/@angular/cli/utilities/config.js:$
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
> at async AddCommand.validateScope (/Users/myuser/Documents/desarrollos/CODIGO/gateway/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/co$
> at async AddCommand.validateAndRun (/Users/myuser/Documents/desarrollos/CODIGO/gateway/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/c$
> at async Object.runCommand (/Users/myuser/Documents/desarrollos/CODIGO/gateway/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/command-r$
> at async default_1 (/Users/myuser/Documents/desarrollos/CODIGO/gateway/node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/cli/index.js:62:31)

i had node 12.x.x LTS and angular 9.0
to try to fix it i did the following
updated node to 14.16.0 LTS and
ng update @angular/core@10 @angular/cli@10
to update angular.

i have also run  npm audit fix, npm cache clear, npm cache verify before and after the update.

running on macOs big sur.
Thank you.

Comment: Did you try reinstalling everything? Make sure you have a clean install. Also, might I suggest you try using NVM? https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm

It helped me before with issues like this.

Comment: Hi, thank you. well i downloaded node and tried to install angular (no update) but the error still is showing.

Comment: Can you try and to the following: 
- remove `node_modules` ( `rm -rf node_modules` )
- manually edit `package.json` and place the following entry in the file: " "@angular/material": "^8.0.2"," inside the dependencies
- Run `npm install`

Comment: If that works, you will manually have to configure angular/material but at least, you'll add it as a dependency to the project.

Comment: just make sure to "change" the "8.0.2" with the version you'd like to have installed.

Comment: I have not installed angular/material in my environment so i can not find " "@angular/material": "^8.0.2", in my package.json

Comment: I've explained the whole process to you in the answer below, and given you a working repository I tested locally that should hopefully work if you match the versions I created with. That should give you a good start to fix the issue you're having. Good luck, and hope it helps!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's try to do this together and step by step. I will go over every step locally, and it should work for you as well.

Let's first make sure we're running the same `node` and `npm` versions.

```
$ node --version
v15.9.0
$ npm --version
7.5.3
```

Let's make sure now that we have no previous versions of `angular-cli` installed on our machine:

```
$ npm -g list
...
├── @angular/cli@11.2.2
└── npm@7.5.3
```

Since I have a version installed, I'd first like to remove it.

```
$ npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
```

Okay, now let's install a fresh version of `@angular/cli`

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Now, let's create a new project:

```
ng new my-dream-app
# yes
# yes
# CSS
```

Let us further CD into it, and make sure we're running

```
cd my-dream-app
ng serve
```

You should be able to see it running now.

Okay, and now for angular material.
Stop the server, and let's add this dependency.

```
ng add @angular/material
# Indigo pink
# Yes
# Yes
```

Let's run the server again:

```
ng serve
```

Let's make sure we're running by adding the following to `app-module.ts`

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    // other imports 
    MatSliderModule,
  ],
```

And then change our HTML `app.component.html` to be like this:

```
<!-- <router-outlet></router-outlet> -->
<mat-slider min="1" max="100" step="1" value="1"></mat-slider>
```

You should see a slider on your browser test site.

---

If all else fails, I've created a repository that's configured and working with the versions I've shown you.

What you want to do is just clone it, and run the necessary commands:

```
git clone https://github.com/dev-cyprium/angular-with-material.git
cd angular-with-material
npm install
ng serve
```

Now, navigate to the browser and you should see the slider component.

Answer (score 0):

I did a small example with a new project created with jhipster, and checked the angular.json file created at the root of the project and it turns out that the file was containing this fragment

```
  "styles": [],
```

so i deleted it and run again

```
ng add @angular/material
```

and the problem was gone.